# Может ли функция создавать переменные?

Tags: javascript

Есть функция:

```js
function createVar(названиеПеременно, значениеПеременной) {

  let названиеПеременно = значениеПеременной;
  return названиеПеременно;
}

createVar('первая', 'значение1');
createVar('вторая', 'значение2');

//createVar(первая, 'значение');

console.log(первая)
```

Допустим я получаю из вне некоторые данные. И данные разные.
И при каждом вызове функции `createVar`, я должен присвоить полученную информацию новой переменной.

Как такое реализовать?

> Хочу отметить сразу, что могу создать объект и при вызове функции
>   создавать ключ и значение и запушить в объект. Такой вариант уже
>   реализован.

Этот вопрос несет в себе, лично для меня, расширяющий кругозор, значения.

Comment: Какая область видимости должна быть? Если говорим про javascript то пишите в глобальный объект `window.name = value`

Comment: @Talleyran, глобальная естественно

Comment: Само использование `let` подразумевает, что создается локальная переменная.

Comment: ну ошибся человек, что сразу набросились то)

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko, ну да ты прав... Это уже привычка...Почти везде `let` использую

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```js
function CreateVar(varName, varValue) {
  window[varName] = varValue;
  return varName;
}

CreateVar("one", 1);
CreateVar("two", 2);

console.log(one); //1
console.log(two); //2
```

Comment: Вот нутром чувствовал, что не с той стороны на задачу смотрел...)))

Comment: Загрязнять `window` - это моветон.

Comment: @Suvitruf, а как тогда выйти из ситуации? Что не моветон?

Comment: @Air не загрязнять.

Answer (score 3):

В дополнение к ответу выше. Знаю, что eval - evil ;)

```js
let createVar0 = (variable, value) => {
  value = (typeof value === "string" ? `'${value}'` : value);
  eval(`var ${variable} = ${value};`); //в переделах блока

  console.log(first); //определена
}

createVar0("first", "значение");
```

Comment: Так много вариантов, а я ни одного не знал...)))  Благодарю

Comment: Вообще `eval` опасно использовать, но решение имеет разрешение на существование, плюс.

Answer (score 2):

Используйте setter.
Вот вариант просто создания переменных с каким-то значением value.

```js
function createVar(...args) {
  for (var key in args) {
   Object.defineProperty(window, args[key], {value: args[key], configurable: true, writable: true, enumerable: true })
   }
}
createVar('первая', 'значение1');
createVar('вторая', 'значение2');
console.log(первая,значение1,вторая,значение2);
```

А этот вариант с присваиванием.

```js
function createVar(variable, value) {
 Object.defineProperty(window, variable, {value: value, configurable: true, writable: true, enumerable: true })
}
createVar('первая', 'значение1');
createVar('вторая', 'значение2');
console.log(первая,вторая);
```

Comment: Тоже благодарю...